# HSQL using java taking to long to close connection

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am using HSQL as a DB for a program that has 20 tables.
After execution when I try to close connection it takes about 4 seconds to close connections of all these 20 tables. I need to do this continuously so in all it takes too long.

Currently I am closing the connection as below for all the tables individually

```
objStatement.execute("SHUTDOWN");
objConnection.close();
```

Here is the part of log file that I am maintaining for the same

Establishing Connection   Fri Apr 25 15:23:01 IST 2014
  Established Connection    Fri Apr 25 15:23:01 IST 2014

Starting to Close Connection  Fri Apr 25 15:23:01 IST 2014
  Closed Connection     Fri Apr 25 15:23:04 IST 2014

Is there a way to do it more efficiently and quickly?

I am using HSQL Database Engine 1.8.0.7 through JAVA

Comment: In most scenarios, you shouldn't have to constantly close a connection. It's usually preferred to create a pool of shared connections and keep them alive until they are no longer needed (e.g. the end of the program)

Comment: @Roberto
I have created a pool of all these 20 connections as of now that brought the exceution from 15secs to 5 secs.
But still it is working too slow.

Comment: The SHUTDOWN command shuts down the whole database. You should use this only when you close your application.